# Using SSL Certificate for WCF-BasicHttp Send Adapter in Biztalk

Tags: ssl-certificate, biztalk

I have a business process which send messages to SAP via soap endpoint exposed by them.
I am using WCF-BasicHttp Send Adapter(In-Process).

As you can see below, earlier the url was http, now they have moved their system to cloud so now they have https endpoints.

I wanted to test this change from http->https, so I have modified the url to https, fill in the credentials for basic auth. it working fine in Test system without SSL Certificate, I need to make sure it wont cause any issue after moving to production system.

My Question is,
1/ Will it work in Production system too as its in TEST without SSL Certificate ?
2/ or Do I need to apply SSL for WCF-BasicHttp Adapter, if yes How can I do that ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are moving to https URL, Certificate is must for SSL/TLS handshake. Many times, Certificate used by specific endpoint is signed by a third party Trusted Root CA e.g. Trustwave, DigiCert etc and these Root CA certs are already trusted on most of the systems. It’s possible in your test system, your endpoint certificate Root CA is already trusted and that’s why you did’t need to install the certificate. In order to check this, you can do following:

1. Browse your https service url in browser in chrome/IE
2. Look for Security/Lock sign to find it’s cert. Clicking the lock sign will open certificate.
3. Check the certificate root by going to Certification Path. You should see a chain of certificates in path. A cert can be by signed by just root CA Or by Intermediary CA first and then root CA. e.g.

—- Trustwave Root
—- Trustwave Intermediary
—- service cert

Or

—- Some Root
—- service cert

4. Check if Root CA is in your Trusted Root store of system. And Intermediary Cert (if applicable) is in Intermediary Cert Store. You can check this by opening certificate mmc snap-in using `mmc` command in Windows->Run and adding Certificates snap in of local computer.
5. If Root CA Cert and Intermediary Certs are not in your system store. SSL/TLS handshake will not complete successfully and BizTalk send port will not work.
6. If these are installed, you should be good. Otherwise install these certificates in local computer stores.

Another way to verify if endpoint certificate is trusted on a BizTalk system is to login with service account under which your send host is running and then browse the URL in IE. If you don’t get any Cert error, and URL opens such as wsdl URL, then you are good. If you get a cert error, this means end point certificate is not trusted and you need to install the certs as described above.

Some references:
[View Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in)
[Working with Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates)

Comment: I checked the https url in TEST & PROD systems in internet explorer browser and there are no errors and could see those endpoints are having valid certificates. So does that mean I don't need to apply certificate on Biztalk box for WCF-BasicHttp Send Adapter ??. My understanding about this whole SSL Certificate is to if I am connecting to any of the HTTPS endpoint I need to have a SSL Certificate from the team managing that particular endpoint and apply that Certificate on my side whether that is in IIS or in Biztalk Server box, is it correct ?

Comment: Also following the steps, I could see that my trusted root CA list has issuer CA. So if this is not the case I would have needed to install and apply certificate to WCF-BasicHttp Send port on Biztalk box right. Also can you explain how would I be able to do that in BizTalk case ??

Comment: In that case you will just need to install CA cert in trusted root in BizTalk box. There are many ways to install certs. One easy way is to open cert in IE following the same step as above, open each certificate in certification path, and copy it to file as .cer file. Once it is copied, you can double click to install it. Depending on which cert you r installing, you need to select appropriate store e.g. root cert goes to Trusted Root CA, intermediary goes to intermediary.

Comment: As Vikas has explained, if the certificate on the endpoint is from a trusted CA, you don't need to apply it at the BizTalk end, it will work as is.   It is only untrusted certs where either you need to trust the CA by adding their public cert or add the public cert of the certificate to your certificate store if it is self signed and not from a CA